# Convert javascript object tree to a printable string for viewing?

Tags: javascript, html

I have created this a number of times, but I want to see if anyone else has a better algorithm for converting a JavaScript object to a formatted string for displaying to a user.  This is NOT for synchronizing (otherwise, just use JSON.stringify()), this is for displaying in a format that is easily readable and navigable by a user.

MAJOR EDIT:

Let me be more specific:  I would like to convert a JavaScript object to HTML elements in order to provide a navigable tree structure.  Consider the following object in JSON notation:

```
var bob = { 
    id: 1, 
    name: "bob", 
    orders: [{id:1, name:"ord1"}, {id:2, name:"ord2"}], 
    otherObj: { 
      id: "anotherObj", 
      grandchild: { id: "anotherObj" }
    }
};
```

I would like to convert the above into HTML DOM objects that would form a tree structure that displays the object tree in a manner that displays all of the children of "bob", with the arrays and objects collapsed, and provides the ability to drill-down (expand) on those child objects.

I don't want to be too specific on the output format, as I will accept any creative manner of outputting the object tree.  I would simply prefer that it be expandable and collapsible for drill-down purposes.

Comment: `JSON.stringify( obj, null, "\t")`

Comment: Would you say XML is more readable than JSON?

Comment: Why not just `console.log(bob)` and have the browser do this for you? Chrome at least has an expandable list view for objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you search for "json tree view" you'll find a number of such implementations.

For example:

- the [dijit tree](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/Tree.html), part of the dojo toolkit
- this [online tool](http://jsontree.com/)
- etc.